# How to move stack to heap in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c

I need help in resolving a warning in Visual Studio 2019.

My program intends to initialize, with zeroes, a 1000x1000 integer matrix and receive an input string of the form "Turn ON 12,45 through 56,78", or "Turn OFF 12,45 through 56,78", or "Toggle 12,45 through 56,78", where the digits are a pair of coordinates. It then prints to screen certain parts of the input string viz. ON, OFF, Toggle, and the coordinates.

When I choose the "Start Without Debugging" option, the output is not as expected and I get warning:

[image]

I read through [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=msvc-160) on the topic and followed the instructions under "To suppress the warning in the IDE" to no avail. I went through similar questions on stackoverflow but that didn't help either.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define row_max 1000
#define column_max 1000

int instruction(char [], int, int, int, int);

int instruction(char light_status[],int row_start, int column_start, int row_end, int column_end)
{
    printf("Enter an instruction\n");
    scanf_s("%s", light_status, 7);

    if (strcmp(light_status, "exit"))//strcmp results in 0 if the operands are equal
    {
        if (!strcmp(light_status, "toggle"))
            scanf_s("%d,%d %*s %d,%d", &row_start, &column_start, &row_end, &column_end);
        else
            scanf_s("%s %d,%d %*s %d,%d", light_status, 4, &row_start, &column_start, &row_end, &column_end);

        printf("Status %s\nrow_start %d\ncolumn_start %d\nrow_end %d\ncolumn_end %d\n\n", light_status, row_start, column_start, row_end, column_end);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The End\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char light_status[7];
    int row, column, grid[row_max][column_max], row_start = 0, column_start = 0, row_end = 0, column_end = 0;

    //Initialising grid to 0
    for (row = 0; row < row_max; row++)
        for (column = 0; column < column_max; column++)
            *(*(grid + row) + column) = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        instruction(light_status, row_start, column_start, row_end, column_end);//extract important data from each instruction
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include error/warning messages in text in your post, not in an external image.

Comment: If you make it a `static` array that will be on the heap. Suppressing the warning is not an option: the array is too large to safely be on the stack. Only suppress warnings if you are *really sure*, for example if you are using the standard `scanf()`  and not MS's own `scanf_s()` and don't want them nagging you.

Comment: regarding: `char light_status[7];` and `scanf_s("%s", light_status, 7);`  This is not a large enough buffer for an instruction like: `Toggle 12,45 through 56,78`  Please clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: @user3629249 the input is read up to the first whitespace, and `"Toggle"` does fit, although the advice not to use small arrays is good.

Comment: regarding: `*(*(grid + row) + column) = 0;`  This seems to not produce the location desired in the 'grid'  Suggest: `*(*(grid + row*column_max) + column) = 0;`  Or much better: `grid[ row ][ column ] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The `grid` array is very large and takes 4'000'000 bytes assuming (`int` is 32 bit).

As it is a local variable, it is allocated on the stack, and latter is usually not very large.

You have basically 4 options:

- you declare it `static`:

  ```
  static int grid[row_max][column_max];
  ```
- you move the `grid` array out of the `main` function so it becomes a global variable.
- as the warning suggests: you move it to the heap by using dynamic memory allocation. I'd not recommend this, because allocating a 2D array dynamically is somewhatpainful.
- you increase the stack size somewhere in the project settings (I don't recommend this either).

Comment: but what troubles 4mb stack may cause? it's just like to have app with 4 threads. it's np really

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I'm not sure if I understood your comment. On Linux the stack size is 8Mb but on Windows it's only 1Mb if I remember correctly.

Comment: that's by default

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин yes, you can change the stack size, but IMO it's a poor solution. What if your array takes 100MB? Should we increase the stack size to 100 MB?

Comment: it's like simd vs multiple instructructions. here you can go with simd

Comment: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Unlimited-OR-Auto-Stack-Size-for-Windows/m-p/956443/highlight/true#M93542     So it's up to 2gb but with risk of app will be denied to launch. so 100 mb is np too , but you should weight it

Answer (score -1):

suggest:  remove this from `main()`

```
grid[row_max][column_max],
```

and before any function definition and after the `#define`s insert:

```
int grid[row_max][column_max];
```

Comment: Not my DV. Probably because of the non existant explanation.

Comment: I downvoted. I don't think we should be leading novices to global variables as answers only last resorts.

Answer (score -2):

just increase stack size in progect settings. stack is way much faster than a heap